# How do I return the Instagram Realtime subscription challenge?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, instagram

I'm trying to subscribe to a tag. It appears that the callback URL is being called correctly with a `hub.challenge` and `hub.mode`, and I figured out how to access the challenge using `self.request.get('hub.challenge')`. I thought I was just supposed to echo the challenge, but that doesn't appear to work since I receive the following errors in the GAE logs:

```
InstagramAPIError: (400) APISubscriptionError-Challenge verification failed. Sent "647bf6dbed31465093ee970577ce1b72", received "
647bf6dbed31465093ee970577ce1b72
".
```

Here is the full handler:

```
class InstagramHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        def process_tag_update(update):
            update = update

        mode         = self.request.get('hub.mode')
        challenge    = self.request.get('hub.challenge')
        verify_token = self.request.get('hub.verify_token')
        if challenge:
            template_values = {'challenge':challenge}
            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../templates/instagram.html')
            html = template.render(path, template_values)
            self.response.out.write(html)
        else:
            reactor = subscriptions.SubscriptionsReactor()
            reactor.register_callback(subscriptions.SubscriptionType.TAG, process_tag_update)

            x_hub_signature = self.request.headers.get('X-Hub-Signature')
            raw_response    = self.request.data
            try:
                reactor.process('INSTAGRAM_SECRET', raw_response, x_hub_signature)
            except subscriptions.SubscriptionVerifyError:
                logging.error('Instagram signature mismatch')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So returning it as a string worked. I should have payed closer attention to the error message, but it took a helpful person on the Python IRC to point out the extra line breaks in the message. Once I put the template files on one line, it seemed to work. I can now confirm that my app is authorized via Instagram's list subscription URL.